# How to place closed Bezier curve on surface of object?

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to create a closed curve on an object, so I can fill it up. I added a Bezier curve and in Edit Mode I changed the Spline Type to Poly. Then I clicked on the object where I want the curve and press 'E' to draw lines of the curve. To close the curve I use Toggle Cyclic. After converting this curve to a mesh I am able to fill the curve up. The problem is that this curve lays not perfectly on the surface of my irregular object. Does anyone know how to bring this curve to the face of the object?
[image]

I know you can use the draw function with the Bezier curve and set depth to surface, but with this function I have problems to create a nice closed curve.

Comment: have you tried drawing the curve with snapping mode on?